# Rouche's theorem - show $z^5+7z-1$ has 3 zeros inside the disc $|z|<1.65$

Tags: complex-analysis

How would you go about showing that $z^5+7z-1$ has $3$ zeros inside the disc $|z|<1.65$? I think usually you'd make $f(z)=z^5+7z-1$ and $g(z)$ something that's in $f(z)$ but I'd need to make $g(z)$ something with degree $3$ I think in order to show that $f(z)$ has $3$ zeros inside $|z|<1.65$ but there isn't a $z^3$ term in $f(z)$.

Comment: do you really have to use Rouche's theorem ? I would plot instead $h(t) = \text{arg} f(1.65 e^{it})$ unwrapped

Comment: Yes I have to unfortunately

Comment: hey @user1952009 are you talking about the Argument Principle? In any case, could you explain to me how you'd solve it? You suggested plotting $h(t)$, how do you do that?

Comment: Approximate roots are `[-1.18450230+1.15139008j, -1.18450230-1.15139008j, 1.11307798+1.15173436j,  1.11307798-1.15173436j, 0.14284865+0.j]` with absolute values `[ 1.65189128,  1.65189128,  1.60169742,  1.60169742,  0.14284865]`. Roots so close to the circle usually make the direct application of Rouche close to impossible.

Comment: Okay so @LutzL what other methods are possible do you think? I've read about the argument principle but I wouldn't really know how to apply it

Comment: You could compare with $$g(x)=\left(\left(z+\frac1{28}\right)^4+7\right)\cdot\left(z-\frac17\right)$$ where you know where the roots are. You could, if numerical methods are allowed, use root approximations and compute Gershgorin-Weierstrass disks, see Durand-Kerner method on wiki.

Comment: [there is the plot of $\frac{1}{2\pi}Im(\log (1.65 e^{it}))$](http://www.paris8.free.fr/arg_f_unwrapped.jpg) I meant. $ \ \ $(using the argument principle) it becomes a rigorous proof once you showed the estimation of $Im(\log f(z))$ I computed is correct up to an error  $< \frac{2\pi }{\delta}$, and that $|f'(z)/f(z)| < 2\pi /\delta$ on $|z| = 1.65$, where $1/\delta$ is the sampling rate I used ($\delta=0.001$)

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in the comments, the [Durand-Kerner method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durand%E2%80%93Kerner_method) allows to give some numerical proof of root inclusion as all roots of a polynomial $f$ of degree $d$ and with root approximations $r_i$ are contained in the collection of disks $$D(r_i+w_i, (d-1)|w_i|)$$ where the $w_i$ are the Weierstrass updates 
$$w_i=-\frac{f(r_i)}{\prod_{j\ne i}(r_i-r_j)}.$$
If the updates are small enough, the inclusion disks can even be reduced to $D(r_i+w_i, \frac14|w_i|)$.

Using the roots of the close-by polynomial
$$
g(x)=\left(\left(z+\frac1{28}\right)^4+7\right)\cdot\left(z-\frac17\right)
\\
=z^5 - 0.01275510204081633⋅z^3 - 0.0009110787172011663⋅z^2 + 6.999975596105789⋅z  - 1.000000232418040
$$
as initial approximations, a q'n'd Python implementation is

```
def f(z): return z**5+7*z-1;
roots = [ 7**0.25/2**0.5*q-1./28 for q in [1+1j,1-1j,-1-1j,-1+1j] ]
roots.append(1./7)
for k in range(10):
    print "    ------round %2d --------------"%(k+1)
    w = [ -f(z) for z in roots ]
    for i in range(5):
        for j in range(5):
            if j!= i: w[i]/=(roots[i]-roots[j]);

    for i in range(5):
        roots[i] += w[i]
        print "    root in disk at %s radius %g, in annulus (%f,%f)" % ( roots[i], 4*abs(w[i]), abs(roots[i])-4*abs(w[i]), abs(roots[i])+4*abs(w[i]))
    if max(abs(e) for e in w) < 1e-3: break
```

and gives the report

```
------round  1 --------------
root in disk at (1.1130787916+1.15173522941j) radius 0.00834119, in annulus (1.593357,1.610040)
root in disk at (1.1130787916-1.15173522941j) radius 0.00834119, in annulus (1.593357,1.610040)
root in disk at (-1.18450311371-1.15139092524j) radius 0.00737156, in annulus (1.644521,1.659264)
root in disk at (-1.18450311371+1.15139092524j) radius 0.00737156, in annulus (1.644521,1.659264)
root in disk at (0.142848644232-2.26339612502e-22j) radius 3.39945e-05, in annulus (0.142815,0.142883)
------round  2 --------------
root in disk at (1.11307797655+1.15173436215j) radius 4.76058e-06, in annulus (1.601693,1.601702)
root in disk at (1.11307797655-1.15173436215j) radius 4.76058e-06, in annulus (1.601693,1.601702)
root in disk at (-1.18450229931-1.15139007541j) radius 4.70823e-06, in annulus (1.651887,1.651896)
root in disk at (-1.18450229931+1.15139007541j) radius 4.70823e-06, in annulus (1.651887,1.651896)
root in disk at (0.142848645525+2.11593205017e-26j) radius 5.17236e-09, in annulus (0.142849,0.142849)
```

where in the last step one can count the number of roots inside the disk $D(0,1.65)$ to get $3$.